# Modular characters (Y)

Tags: number-theory

I am reading the proof of following proposition from the book "A course in Arithmetic" from J-P Serre:

Let a be a non-zero square-free integer and let $m = 4 \cdot |a|$. Then there exists a unique character $\chi_a$ modulo $m$ such that $\chi_a(p) = \left(\frac{a}{p} \right)$ for all prime numbers $p$ not dividing $m$. One has $\chi_a ^2 = 1$ and $\chi_a \neq 1$ if $a \neq 1$.

The book states for the proof of the uniqueness part:
The uniqueness of $\chi_a$ is clear because all integers prime to $m$ are products of prime numbers not dividing $m$.

Why is this clear? I just don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b\in\Bbb Z$. If $\gcd(b,m)>1$ then $\chi(b)$ must equal zero.
Otherwise $\gcd(b,m)=1$, and then $b\equiv b'$ for some $b'$ with $0<b<m$, and also $\gcd(b',m)=1$. In this case $\chi(b)$ must equal $\chi(b')$. Furthermore
$b'=p_1\ldots p_k$, where the $p_j$ are primes, and none divides $m$, so there are
all odd. Then $\chi(b)$  must equal $\chi(p_1)\cdots\chi(p_k)=\left(\frac{a}{p_1}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{a}{p_k}\right)$. So $\chi$ is be unique.